# Simple Search: Passing Form Variable to URI Using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a search form on each of my pages. If I use form helper, it defaults to `$_POST`. I'd like the search term to show up in the URI:

```
http://example.com/search/KEYWORD
```

I've been on Google for about an hour, but to no avail. I've only found articles on how `$_GET` is basically disabled, because of the native URI convention. I can't be the first person to want this kind of functionality, am I? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a better fix if you're dealing with people without JS enabled.

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('ad/pre_search');?>
   <input type="text" name="keyword" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    function pre_search()
    {
        redirect('ad/search/.'$this->input->post('keyword'));
    }

    function search()
    {
        // do stuff;
    }
?>
```

I have used this a lot of times before.

Comment: Thorpe - how do you deal with apostrophe's?

Comment: You should modify this in the config file: 
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
to
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '\'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Comment: I know this is a super old question, but just saved me some major headaches - cheers!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no method of accomplishing this with a simple POST. However, you can access the form via Javascript and update the destination. For example:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return changeurl();" method="POST">
<input id="keyword">
</form>

<script>
function changeurl()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword");

    form.action = "http://mysite.com/search/"+escape(keyword.value);

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: issue with Codeigniter here -- apostrophe's in the search string will not be accepted by the CI URI library: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post on how to enable GET query strings together with segmented urls.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56389/#277621

After enabling that you can use the following method to retrieve the additional variables.

```
// url = http://example.com/search/?q=text
$this->input->get('q');
```

This is better because you don't need to change the permitted_uri_chars config setting. You may get "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" error if you simply put anything the user enters in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$pieces = explode("/", $uri);

$uri_3 = $pieces[3];
```

Thanks [erunways](http://erunways.com)!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about CodeIgniter, but it's PHP, so shouldn't `$_GET` still be available to you? You could format your URL the same way Google does: `mysite.com/search?q=KEYWORD` and pull the data out with `$_GET['q']`.

Besides, a search form seems like a bad place to use POST; GET is bookmarkable and doesn't imply that something is changing server-side.

Comment: No.  "GET" is disabled in Codeigniter