# Codeigniter put variable in front of the page uri segment using the pagination class

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to build a search functionality with pagination using codeigniter. The problem is I can't get to put the search query on the Url in front of the the page number so that I access it using the get method from my controller. How can I get the url to display like below:

```
http://localhost/project/shop/2/search?search_query=bolts
```

The 2 being the uri segment that the pagination class uses to identify the page number. Below is part of the pagination class config in my controller:

```
$search_query=$this->input->get('search_query');

 $config['base_url'] = base_url().'shop/search?search='.$search_query;
 $config['total_rows'] = $this->ProductModel->countallByTerm($search query);
 $config['per_page'] = 2;

 $start = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

 $data['products']=$this->ProductModel->search($search_query, $config['per_page'], $start);
 $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

And when I click the 'next page' on my pagination link it is generating the url below:

```
 http://localhost/project/shop/search?search=bolts/2
```

This is my html code in the view with the form responsible for submitting the search query:

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo site_url('shop/search') ?>" method="get">
        <div class="input-field col md10 s10">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
          <input type="text" name="search" class="validate" required>
          <label for="search">Search Products</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col md2 s2">
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="search" name="submit" value="">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Please help

Comment: can you create an URL like this :http://localhost/project/shop/2/bolts  So that you can directly take the parameters as an Url Segment.

Comment: ok. that helps. but how do i submit a form value  to a URI segment

Comment: You can achieve that with Jquery ,that is on click of any submit button after entering the search field you can redirect it to the above mentioned url.

Comment: Post your HTML code so that it will be helpfull to answer.

Comment: Thanx, i have edited my question and put the html code

Comment: i have written an answer based on your form for redirecting it to the controller ,please check it..

Comment: I have found a solution on this previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227470/simple-search-passing-form-variable-to-uri-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Change your Form as follows:

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo site_url('shop/search') ?>" method="get">
        <div class="input-field col md10 s10">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
          <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="validate" required>
          <label for="search">Search Products</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col md2 s2">
          <input type="button" id="SubmitButtonForForm" class="btn" value="search" name="submit" value="">
        </div>
      </form>
```

And you also have to do the Processing with JQuery:

```
var url = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>';//Made Changes Here.
//It will output the current Page's URl for EG:http://localhost/project/shop/2  
//1 or 2 or... based on your pagination.

$("#SubmitButtonForForm").on("click",function(e){
   //Add your Code for Validations Here and put a condition that if the form is validated then only process the following code.
   var searchString = $("#search").val();
   e.PreventDefault();
   var redirectURl = url + "/" + searchString;
   //Redirect with window location method of javascript.
   window.location = redirectURl;
})
```

Comment: thank you. but as i specified in my question, the problem only comes when is click the next page button, on form submision the first 2 results are coming out fine but when i click the "next page" button to view the next set of results that when the URL gets mashed up. Secondly,  the form submit button is no longer working. the console is outputting: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags**. The form is only submitting when i hit enter.

Comment: What is the Url that is generated for Cliking the "Next Page"? And second we have changed the submit button to simple button so that we can redirect to the custom URL instead of Form action.

Comment: this the URL being generated when the form is submitted and is giving me an accurate first set of results: **http://localhost/shop/shop/search?search=bolts**. And this is the url being generated when i click the 'next page' button: **http://localhost/shop/shop/search/bolts/2**. Because the search variable is lost and because the codeigniter pagination class is the one which generates the page number **2**, my second set of results become inaccurate.

Comment: so to make all the things working you have to make following url in the first page when search functionality is used: localhost/shop/shop/search/bolts/1

Comment: And based on Search results if many results are coming then your paginatio will work with following link : localhost/shop/shop/search/bolts/2